# How to get iframe's readyState

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my html

```
<div ng-if="isLoadDone" class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="text-center"><span class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-5x fa-fw margin-bottom"></span></div>
  </div>
<iframe id="appId" ng-if="isLoadDone" class="app-iframe" ng-src="{{trustedApplUrl}}"></iframe>
```

And in javascript:

```
$elem = angular.element('#appId');
```

In debug console

```
$elem show as
context:document
   .......
   readyState: "complete"
```

I don't know how to get the readyState by using $elem
$elem.context.document.readyState didn't work. Any idea how to get the readyState by using $elem
Thanks

Comment: add a onload="alert('Loaded!');" to your iframes HTML.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `readystatechange` and `onload` to determine it, like:

```
//check for IE
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") > -1 && !window.opera){
    yourIframe.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (yourIframe.readyState == "complete"){
            alert("Iframe is loaded.");
        }
    };
} else {
    yourIframe.onload = function(){
        alert("Iframe is loaded.");
    };
}
```

Note:: IE's `readystatechange` is completely different than the `readystatechange` event fired on `XMLHttpRequest` objects. Starting with Internet Explorer 11, `onload` should be used.